# How to add an object in the array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react . Here , what I have tried.

```
onaddRow(e, id) {
        const addData = this.props.lowData;
        const tempObj = {
            id: 'L1',
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            numberOfQuestions: ''
        }
        addData.push(tempObj);
    }
```

this.props.lowData is an array of the objects . So, I want to add an object in this .

So, I tried the following way but it was not working , can any one suggest me how can I do this ?

Comment: Your example looks like you want to add to the `addData` object but in your question you say you want to add to `this.props.lowData`; which do you want to add to?

Comment: Are you sure that `this.props.lowData` is an array?

Comment: Yes , I mean its the same thing .

Comment: Yes it's an array of objects.

Comment: Did you check if `onaddRow()` was properly called? Because the function body looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get updated array usign (spread) `...` also.

```
onaddRow(e, id) {  
    const tempObj = {
        id: 'L1',
        technologyId: 0,
        technology: '',
        type: '',
        numberOfQuestions: ''
    }
    const addData = [...this.props.lowData, tempObj ];
    console.log(addData)
}
```

//as you asked in comment. if you want to remove item from array you can do like this.

```
let updatedArrray = yourArray.filter(i => {
  return i.id != passYourIdHere;
});
console.log(updatedArrray);
```

so here we are returning all other object's except matching one, finally collecting in updatedArrray.

Comment: Hi, your answer is perfect. Thanks for this. If you dont have any prob then can you tell me How can I now remove the element from that same if using Id I mean  I know Id so if it matches the ID then remove that elemen.

Comment: have u understood deleting part ?

Comment: Yes I understood that

Answer (score 0):

By using addData.push() you are effectively adding the object into the array (if props.lowData is indeed an array of objects), but given that you are on a React environment you should do afterward **this.setState({lowData:addData})** in order to trigger the rerendering of the component.

Answer (score 0):

React uses one-way data flow (from parent to children). In your example you received data from parent in props. For adding new object you must pass callback from parent which will add it to the parent state.

```
Child component:
onAddRow(e, id) {  
    const tempObj = {
        id: 'L1',
        technologyId: 0,
        technology: '',
        type: '',
        numberOfQuestions: ''
    }
    this.props.onAddRow(tempObj)
}

Parent:

onAddRow = (newObj) => {
 this.setState({
   lowData: [...this.state.lowData, newObj]
 })
}
render() {

<ChildComponent data={this.state.lowData} onAddRow={this.onAddRow} />

}
```